# VBA Code works on one tab and not others

Tags: excel, vba, macos

the code below only seems to run when I am on the 'Site' tab and no other tab. Can somebody explain why?

```
Sub GroupReport()

Dim vRegion As String

vRegion = Sheets("Region").Range("A3").Value

Sheets("Site").Cells.AutoFilter

Sheets("Site").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vRegion

Sheets("Site").Range("B2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Region").Range("A8")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Site")` tells the macro which sheet to work on.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That doesn't explain why the code doesn't work when other sheets are active.

Comment: Fix this piece of code: `Sheets("Site").Range("B2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Copy` to this `Sheets("Site").Range("B2", Sheets("Site").Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Copy`. As currently written once activated from another active sheet it's trying to grab `Sheets("Site").Range("B2")` to `ActiveSheet.Range("B2")...` which doesn't make sense to the Excel Object model.

Comment: Guys, please don't answer in comments

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in your code, you're running a procedure on the `Site` worksheet:

```
Sheets("Site")
```

You're applying filters and copying ranges but referencing this procedures only for:

```
Sheets("Site").Cells.AutoFilter

Sheets("Site").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vRegion

Sheets("Site").Range("B2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Region").Range("A8")
```

If you want your macro to run on all `worksheets` or "tabs" use the [`ActiveSheet` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-activesheet-property-excel).

```
Option Explicit

Sub GroupReport()

Dim vRegion As String

vRegion = Sheets("Region").Range("A3").Value

With ActiveSheet

    .Cells.AutoFilter
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vRegion
    .Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Region").Range("A8")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvoted - however if the sheets are all in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the workbook that contains this VBA code), then it would be much more robust to use the worksheet's `CodeName` instead of dereferencing them from the `Sheets` collection, and working off the `ActiveSheet` (implicitly or explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good practice to declare the sheet variables to hold the reference of the sheets the code is dealing with.
Also, always qualify the range fully with the sheet reference.

Please give this a try...

```
Sub GroupReport()
Dim wsSite As Worksheet, wsRegion As Worksheet
Dim vRegion As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsSite = Sheets("Site")
Set wsRegion = Sheets("Region")

vRegion = wsRegion.Range("A3").Value

With wsSite
    .Cells.AutoFilter
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=vRegion
    .Range("B2", wsSite.Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=wsRegion.Range("A8")
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```